# Is it possible to add template suggestions for image styles?

Tags: 8, theming, media

I am experimenting with durpal 8 theme hook suggestions. I tried to customize the the theme suggestions based on the style name. I want the ability to add a twig template for each style if I wanted so I tried this:

```
function themename_theme_suggestions_image_style_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  $suggestions[] = [$hook . '__' . $variables['style_name']];
}
```

and

```
function themename_theme_suggestions_image_alter(&$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  $suggestions[] = [$hook . '__' . $variables['style_name']];
}
```

I was expecting to see this as a theme hook suggestion in the html comments printed by in the page source after enabling twig debuging.

Using xdebug the hook is triggered but I don't find it in the suggestions list in the html after enabling   twig.config.debug to true.

am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x) doesn't use a third argument.
2. You are supposed to add the suggestions as string.

---

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_image_style_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '__' . $variables['style_name'];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_image_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '__' . $variables['style_name'];
}
```

Comment: [the $hook param is not required but it does get passed](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x) to hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter . Not sure why it's not in the documentation you referenced. But it's indeed the array that I did not catch. Not sure how I missed it ... thanks

Comment: I wish there was a way to come back and upvote an answer that I'd already upvoted from a while back. Thanks again for the fish!